# Firebase Extension Translate Text in Firestore does not allow to add more than one input and output field

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

I am trying to use the [Translate Text](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-translate-text) extension in order to translate a few fields from my collection to 5 different languages.

But the configuration screen only allows me to choose one field for input and one field for output, respectively.

[image: Config]]

If I try to separate two different fields by commas, it is still recognized as one field, and as a result I get this:

[image: Names separated by commas]]

How can I choose two fields for input and two fields for output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for a single instance of the extension.

What you could do instead is configure two different instances of the extension, each one configured to use different input and output fields.

Feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) if you would like to see improvements to the extension.

Comment: Since I am new to Firebase, I did not know that I can add multiple instances of extensions. Thank you, that works very well.